# How to play a WAV when my timer finishes?

Tags: android, audio, timer, wav, playback

I've been trying to create a countdown that plays a buzzer wav (R.raw.buzzer1) when it runs out of time. Every code I've seen on this site causes my app to force close.  How would I do this? For example,

```
public void onFinish() 
{   
    // play the sound somehow?
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
MediaPlayer mpxmPlayer2;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

             mpxmPlayer2  = new MediaPlayer();
            mpxmPlayer2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.digital_preview);

            cntr_aCounter.start();
        }
        CountDownTimer cntr_aCounter = new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                Log.e("CountDown",millisUntilFinished+"");  
            }

            public void onFinish() {

                mpxmPlayer2.start();

            }
            };
```

Comment: It still force closed on me. What could be causing this? Is there a certain type of WAV file that has to be used with Android?

Comment: but on my side it's working perfectly,ok share logcat messages?

Comment: can you tell me location of wav file in your project?

Comment: 03-10 15:05:07.077: E/MediaPlayer(336): Unable to to create media player
03-10 15:05:07.167: D/MediaPlayer(336): create failed:
03-10 15:05:07.167: D/MediaPlayer(336): java.io.IOException: setDataSourceFD failed.: status=0x80000000

Comment: The location of the wav is res/raw/buzzer1.wav (in Users/Matt/workspace/guessit/